Prevent Entity Framework Core migrations to generate scripts using syntax like $EF$
I'm using Entity Framework Core v6.0.12 and its migrations to generate SQL scripts using:
dotnet ef migrations script --idempotent PreviousMigration CurrentMigration --output Scripts/CurrentMigration.sql

The SQL script that gets generated looks like this:
START TRANSACTION;
DO $EF$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory" WHERE "MigrationId" = '20240606210930_MyAwesomeTableMigration') THEN
    CREATE TABLE "MyAwesomeTables" (
        "Uuid" uuid NOT NULL,
        "Name" text NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT "PK_MyAwesomeTables" PRIMARY KEY ("Uuid")
    );
    END IF;
END $EF$;

DO $EF$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory" WHERE "MigrationId" = '20240606210930_MyAwesomeTableMigration') THEN
    INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
    VALUES ('20240606210930_MyAwesomeTableMigration', '6.0.12');
    END IF;
END $EF$;
COMMIT;
sql

I'm using DbUp to run the scripts and my problem is that $EF$ is considered a variable per https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more-info/variable-substitution/ , so I'm getting the following exception

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Variable EF has no value defined

Current solution is to disable the variables in DbUp with .WithVariablesDisabled(), but I might need them in future so I'm looking for an alternative.

In Postgres a script is actually nothing more than a string. If it strictly that then every tick (single quote ') would need to be escaped or doubled. In order to avoid that a technique of Dollar quoting was introduced.. This takes the form of  $<term>$ and must be matched pairs. That is exactly what your $EF$ is. It appears that Postgres and DbUp are using the same format for conflicting purposes. Seems likely nothing can be done.
